# Merge two series of time intervals in pandas (intersection)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have multiple lists of time intervals and I need to find the time intervals (intersection) that are common to all of them.

E.g.

```
a = [['2018-02-03 15:06:30', '2018-02-03 17:06:30'], # each line is read as [start, end]
     ['2018-02-05 10:30:30', '2018-02-05 10:36:30'],
     ['2018-02-05 11:30:30', '2018-02-05 11:42:32']]

b = [['2018-02-03 15:16:30', '2018-02-03 18:06:30'],
     ['2018-02-04 10:30:30', '2018-02-05 10:32:30']]

c = [['2018-02-01 15:00:30', '2018-02-05 18:06:30']]
```

The result would be

```
common_intv = [['2018-02-03 15:16:30','2018-02-03 17:06:30'],
               ['2018-02-05 10:30:30','2018-02-05 10:32:30']]
```

I've found [this](https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/algorithms/124582/given-two-lists-of-intervals-return-the-intervals-that-overlap-between-the-two-lists) solution that should work also for time intervals but I was wondering whether there is a more efficient way to do it in pandas.

The proposed solution in the link would process two lists at a time i.e. it would first find the common intervals between `a` and `b`, then put these common intervals inside a variable `common`, then find the common intervals between `common` and `c` and so on...

Of course a global solution (considering all intervals at the same time) would be even better!

Comment: In this example '2018-02-03 15:16:30' is unique to b. what do you mean by common to all of them?

Comment: each line is an interval. I've added a comment to make it more clear. So  '2018-02-03 15:16:30' is simply the start of an interval for list b (interval that ends at '2018-02-03 18:06:30')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas.merge_asof` in both directions to get a first selection and then carefully cleanup the resulting rows. Code could be:

```
# build the dataframes and ensure Timestamp types
dfa = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['start', 'end']).astype('datetime64[ns]')
dfb = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=['start', 'end']).astype('datetime64[ns]')
dfc = pd.DataFrame(c, columns=['start', 'end']).astype('datetime64[ns]')

# merge a and b
tmp = pd.concat([pd.merge_asof(dfa, dfb, on='start'),
                 pd.merge_asof(dfb, dfa, on='start')]
                ).sort_values('start').dropna()

# keep the minimum end and ensure end <= start
tmp = tmp.assign(end=np.minimum(tmp.end_x, tmp.end_y))[['start', 'end']]
tmp = tmp[tmp['start'] <= tmp['end']]

# merge c
tmp = pd.concat([pd.merge_asof(tmp, dfc, on='start'),
                 pd.merge_asof(dfc, tmp, on='start')]
                ).sort_values('start').dropna()

tmp = tmp.assign(end=np.minimum(tmp.end_x, tmp.end_y))[['start', 'end']]
tmp = tmp[tmp['start'] <= tmp['end']]
```

It gives as expected:

```
                start                 end
0 2018-02-03 15:16:30 2018-02-03 17:06:30
1 2018-02-05 10:30:30 2018-02-05 10:32:30
```